# Spark write file csv/hive take too much time and performance benchmark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am having a very simple problem with spark, but there is very little information on the web. I have encountered this problem using both pyspark and scala.

The problem is that it takes a lot of time to save the csv / hive file.

Here is a very simple piece of code I have.

```
spark = SparkSession.
sql = '''
select * from some_table
'''
df = spark.sql(sql)
df.write.csv(path)
```

This code is very simple, but a 200,000 volume of data can take about 30-40 minutes, and a 10 million volume of data can take hours. Even `repartition(1)` does not significantly improve write performance. `saveAsTable` (to hive) may be better, but it is still an unacceptable amount of time, and after all, it is much faster to use hive directly. But hive is hard to engineer as a big project.

My question is:

1. Is there a way to improve performance?
2. What is the performance baseline? What is the approximate time for 1 million data in what configuration?

Answer (score 0):

its not number of rows. its number of columns and data too.
what is the size if the table in gb mainly determine dump time.  You can use below commands to get that info.

```
show tblproperties some_table;
or 
analyze table  some_table compute statistics;
```

Now, once you know GB, you can estimate dump time. if its too high, your data dump will take time and you can improve by using

1. add some filters to exclude unwanted data.
2. select only required columns.
3. dump data during night time when system is not busy.
4. check with final consumer and see if you can tune it.

You can try this command to dump into csv data- its easy and faster.

```
hive -e 'select * from some_table' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > /tmp/some_table.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. My data file byte size is only 417679154 and it's 0.4G, I think it should be fast. And of course, I could use hive to dump, but my example is a really simple test example, and the purpose is: 1. Not using hive script in the work and everyone could reuse some functions (spark is better), 2. get result fast. We say 100G needs 30mins, it's ok, 0.4G needs 30mins, hmm, not that ok for me.

Comment: can you please issue `analyze table  some_table compute statistics;` and see the size ?

Comment: Here it is. stats: [numFiles=3, numRows=6755057, totalSize=417679154, rawDataSize=126465776505]. @koushik-roy

Comment: Table has like 6mil rows and 117GB data(rawDataSize=126465776505 bytes). I do not think its 0.4GB. so dumping 117GB in 30min is somewhat fair depending on your network and location of your client.

Comment: dfs -ls -h /user/my_user/dm/*/dt=20211122 shows the files size is only 400m.

Comment: and my `analyze table sql` is `analyze table my_table partition(dt='20211122') compute statistics;` result is [numFiles=3, numRows=6755057, totalSize=417679154, rawDataSize=126465776505], but `dfs -ls -h /my_table/dt=20111122`, show the file size 130m for each (almost 0.4G total).

Comment: How big is the dumped csv file?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old but after couple of trial and errors my team figured out that when we are writing to Csv, we need to make sure the data is repartitioned according to the parallelism required.
For example:

```
Executors used = 30
Repartition before write could be higher 100+
And if data to write is more please increase the repartition and executors count too
```